# Working with If statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I have decided to add the following if Statements to JavaScript

```
  if (form.address == "Vancouver, BC") {
      user.set("address", "#complete address");
} else if (form.address == "Edmonton, AB") {
      user.set("address", "complete address");
} else if (form.address == "Vancouver + United States") {
      user.set("address", "#complete address And 1300 Boblett Street, US");
} else if (form.address == "Edmonton + United States") {
      user.set("address", "complete address");
}
```

and is receiving the following error on console:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Below is the entire code

```
 $scope.signUp = function(form) {
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("password", form.password);
        user.set("username", form.username);
                user.set("fullName", form.fname);

      user.set("companyName", form.cname);
      if (form.address == "Vancouver, BC") {
      user.set("address", "#1001 - 610 Granville Street Vancouver, BC V6C 3J3");
} else if (form.address == "Edmonton, AB") {
      user.set("address", "10915 65th Ave NW Edmonton, AB T6H 1W1");
} else if (form.address == "Vancouver + United States") {
      user.set("address", "#1001 - 610 Granville Street Vancouver, BC V6C 3J3 And 1300 Boblett Street, Unit-B1569 Blaine, WA 98230");
} else if (form.address == "Edmonton + United States") {
      user.set("address", "10915 65th Ave NW Edmonton, AB T6H 1W1 And 1300 Boblett Street, Unit-B1569 Blaine, WA 98230");
} 

           user.set("phoneNumber", form.pnumber);
          user.set("mailingAddress", form.maddress);
          user.set("plan", form.plan);


    user.signUp(null, {
      success: function(user) {
  window.location = 'payment.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
      var div = document.getElementById("signUpError");
    div.textContent = "Unable to sign up: " + error.message;
     scroll(0,0);
      }
    });    
  };
```

Essentially there is a form, and in it there is an option input to select an address where when some for example select new york, it would store into parse the complete address of that location (user only see new york, but the back end stores the full address).

Answer (score 2):

When ever you see this type error, you're calling something as a function which is not defined as a function.
For example:

```
var user = {
set: {
        phone: '',
        address:''
    }
};
user.set("phoneNumber", "form.pnumber");
```

Comment: thank you for your response. would you mind elaborating a bit more and in how i could relate this

Comment: Your example doesn't work as is because of dependencies. We could dig deeper if you post to jsfiddle or jsbin, with HTML, CSS and external js libraries.

Comment: Check out your Dev Tools. You're still getting dependency errors.
"Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module AuthApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'AuthApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."